# Axis and svg text elements hide each other

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bar-chart

I have bar charts in the tooltips, which appear when hovering blue rectangles. There are axis text elements on the left of the bars:

```
 var yScale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(constNames)
        .range([barHeight/2, constResults.length * barHeight + barPadding - barHeight/2]);
      var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
        .tickSize(nameLength)
        .tickPadding(0);
      svg2.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + nameLength + ",0)")
        .style("text-anchor", "start")
        .call(yAxis);
```

On the right of the bars I have text elements with the values:

```
svg2.selectAll("text")
        .data(constResults)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
            return(d + "%");
        })
        .attr("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "central")
        .attr("y", function(d, i) {
            return i*(barHeight + barPadding) + barHeight/2;
        })
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return xScale(d) + nameLength + barPadding/2;
        })
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                .attr("font-size", "12px")
                .attr("fill", "black");
```

And the problem is that when axis text is in gear, svg texts are hiden. When I turn off axis texts, svg texts work ok

It is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/jhf63wpy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
svg2.selectAll("text")
    .data(constResults)
    .enter()
    .append("text");
```

You are selecting all the text elements, and you already have text elements in that SVG. You have to select something else, like this:

```
svg2.selectAll(".secondText")
    .data(constResults)
    .enter()
    .append("text");
```

This is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5xnwwpd/